# When I try to debug, the little blue ball turns into a magnifying glass and stops

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class olPers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer>nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer>mins = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++) {
            int num1=scan.nextInt();
            nums.add(num1);
            int num2=scan.nextInt();
            nums.add(num2);
            int num3=scan.nextInt();
            nums.add(num3);
            Collections.sort(nums);
            int min = nums.get(0);
            mins.add(min);
            
            
        }
        for(int i=0 ;i<mins.size();i++ ) {
            System.out.print(mins.get(i)+" ");
        }
        scan.close();

    }

}
```

I've tried looking on YouTube and I've done exactly what they do but its not working. I'm not very good at debugging so I might just be doing something wrong. When I *step over* or *step in*, the little blue ball becomes a small magnifying glass and its so frustrating.

Comment: What debugger are you using? What IDE?

Comment: eclipse @federico klez Culloca

Comment: The program requires several inputs - are you entering the number when you step over the `scan.nextInt()` lines?

Comment: no, i thought i should run it first so that so that those values are in. but i did try to do it before entering the numbers and it didnt work. could this be the problem